# In Cluster Config is unable to get pods when deployed in a non-default namespace

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

When I deploy my golang service to any namespace but the `default` namespace, the service is unable to retrieve pods on any namespace. The same service deployed on the `default` namespace works perfectly, using the golang client-go api.

Is this a security issue?

Thanks.

Comment: did you check whether or not you service has permission?

Comment: @nightfury1204 Not sure- where do I check that?

Comment: how did you create the client in your golang service?

Comment: @nightfury1204 I used rest.InClusterConfig(config)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is permission issue. Since you are using `rest.InClusterConfig(config)` to create client. That means it using pod's service account as credential. So check whether that service account has the permission to get pods in any namespace.

> if service account in the pod is not defined, then it will use `default` service account.

If RBAC is enabled in your cluster, then check the **role binding** in that namespace, to find out whether your service account has the permission.

```
# to see the list of role bindings in 'default' namespace
kubectl get rolebindings --namespace default
```

To see the specific rolebinding

```
kubectl get rolebindings ROLE-BINDING-NAME --namespace default -o yaml
```

Also you can create role and role binding to give permission. To know about RBAC role and role binding see here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

Answer (score 2):

Following is what I used on a minikube cluster to give the default service account access to crud ops on common resources. The obvious caveat is that you'd need to be careful on a real cluster.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: crud-role
  namespace: default
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "apps", "batch"]
  resources: [ "deployments", "jobs", "pods", "replicasets", "services" ]
  verbs: [ "create", "get", "list", "delete"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: crud-role-binding
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: crud-role
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    namespace: default
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error but from a pod using golang client in default namespace:

*pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope*

Golang code snippet:

```
if configMode == "IN_CLUSTER" {
    // creates the in-cluster config
    config, err := rest.InClusterConfig()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    return config, err
}
```

I used the solution provided by @Gazi but with ClusterRole, that will let you access resources cluster-wide. It was modified for get and list only:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: query-role
  namespace: default
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "apps", "batch"]
  resources: [ "deployments", "jobs", "pods", "replicasets", "services" ]
  verbs: [ "get", "list" ]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: query-role-binding
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: query-role
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    namespace: default
```

Following links are useful:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/